# Azure VM IIS Server - Web Deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created Virtual machine in Azure, i set up server, installed web deploy 3.6, management service 
[image]

But if i want to publish my website to this server i am still getting this error [image]

Comment: You probably need to open up the ports required by Web Deploy in your VMs networking configuration (in the Azure portal), see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later which suggests that 80 and 8172 are the required ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check this [blog](https://blog.tallan.com/2017/05/02/deploying-a-site-to-an-azure-vm-using-web-deploy/).

Please ensure web deploy service is listening. Also, you need open port 8172 on Windows Firewall and Azure NSG.

[image]